# Cannot override exceptionFactory property of Nestjs ValidationPipe

Tags: validation, overriding, nestjs

I want to override `ValidationPipe` to change it's exception format. *I can do this using constructor parameter options but it should be done on every microservice separately. Then I chose this approach*

This is what I did:

```js
export class ClassValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
    console.log('>>>>> This log happens');
    return super.transform(value, metadata);
  }

  exceptionFactory = (errors: ValidationError[]) => {
    console.log('>>>>> But never reaches this log!');
    return new HttpException('My custom error!', 400);
  };
}
```

But the above function never executed and **the output is always just like original ValidatioPipe just like it never been overridden**.

I'm using this pipe like this:

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(new ClassValidationPipe());
```

Comment: Do you have more code you can show for this? I'd expect doing something like this to work. A git repo or something would be great.

Comment: Could not reproduce this error on a new app. Maybe there is some conflicts somewhere else. But where?

Comment: Possibly a globally bound pipe using the `APP_PIPE` provider token. If you can provide access to your repo, someone can probably point out where the issue is. With what's here there isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, there might be different reasons but mine was using another (default) globalPipe.
So I needed to remove:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
```

then the custom one became active:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    exceptionFactory: validationExceptionFactory,
  }),
);
```